# CAML Query works in my VS2010U, but not on anybody else's computer

Tags: client-object-model, error, caml-query

I have a list with records uniquely identified by project numbers. This is column 5 - Col05 in my list. It works fine when I run the code, and I am getting the expected record. I can also read the values I need.

But this doesn't work on anybody else's computer. Error received is:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm working with C# (.net) and Sharepoint Client COM, and using VS 2010. The above error had come earlier once, when trying to convert a SP List Item which is null to string, but there are no such columns for that record - I've checked and every column has some value.

The code I have used for this is below:

```
SP.ClientContext _clientcontext = new SP.ClientContext("https://mysite/");
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential();
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

            SP.Web _site = _clientcontext.Web;
            SP.List _list = _site.Lists.GetByTitle("myList");

            string id = "9999";

            string _viewXML = "" +
                        "<View>" +
                            "<Query>" +
                                "<Where>" +
                                    "<Eq>" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name = '_x0043_ol05'/>" +
                                            "<Value Type = 'Text'>" + id + "</Value>" +
                                        "</FieldRef>" +
                                    "</Eq>" +
                                "</Where>" +
                             "</Query>" +
                          "</View>";

            SP.CamlQuery _query = new SP.CamlQuery { ViewXml = _viewXML };

            SP.ListItemCollection _listitems = _list.GetItems(_query);

            _clientcontext.Load(_listitems);
            _clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I can't figure out how it is working fine when I run it in debug mode/run with debug, but not on anybody elses. Remaining code runs fine, so its not an issue about nothing working at all, but its only this bit that is stuck

Would appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much debugging, found that I had assigned credentials outside this code block. For some reason, it did not throw an error for invalid credentials, even though it was trying to execute a query without the valid username and password.

Throwing a null reference exception threw me off. Here's the code if it helps anybody:

```
            myCred.UserName = mainForm.form1Username;
            myCred.Password = mainForm.form1Password;
            myCred.Domain = "Domain";
            myCache.Add(new Uri("https://myURL/"), "NTLM", myCred);
            _clientcontext.Credentials = myCache;

            _clientcontext.Load(_listitems);
            _clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks a lot to @David Lozzi for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet the null reference is because the column name doesn't exist? Are you deploying the column with the same codeset, or is it manually created with the list? Grab SharePoint Manager, https://spm.codeplex.com/, or use PowerShell, and check out the internal name of the field in each of your environments.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer, David. But I've checked the column names, and this is working code. Like I mentioned, this is working fine on my comp. But doesn't seem to work anywhere else.

Comment: what do you mean when you say deploying the column with the same codeset, or manually created with list? Sorry, I am new to both C# and SP. The list already exists, and I have checked the column name/s. Also, none of the columns are null, all have some value.

Comment: ok, so the lists are already made, good. How are you checking the column names? Are you checking their internal names or their external? What I'm concerned about is that your CAML field name is `_x0043_ol05`, while you stated it's Col05. `_x0043_` is unicode for C, which might not be the same in each environment. If the field was made via SP list settings, the internal name should be Col05. I don't know why you're seeing this special character.

Comment: yes, i've checked. it isn't working with column UI name. but its working fine with internal name. i just cross-checked the results too. its returning the record which I wanted. so this code is working, well, at least on mine.

just as an aside, i created this list manually. went to sharepoint URL> created new list > manually configured the columns by clicking add column.

Adding columns programmatically did not work well for me. Worked fine sometimes, didn;t work at others.

Comment: If the columns are accurate, then something else is acting up. Can you debug it on the other environments? Have you confirmed that the list name is exactly the same as well? Otherwise, I'm not sure what else to look at.

Comment: yes, just checked the list name as well. its correct, since its also returned the data expected. just a side note, I'm working on a Citrix VDI, if that adds to anything. however this hasn't worked for anybody else's regular machine/VDI ...

Comment: I think I missed something. The SharePoint client you're creating, is using one SP environment, but the client isn't working on other users' computers? So it's the same code and same SP environment for all users?

Comment: yup, same code for all. all user have access to the same SP environment, and the client remaining functionalities are working as expected.

Comment: my apologies, I misunderstood. When your client app is compiled, does it include the necessary SharePoint dlls for the project to run? They should be included in the output folder. Your machine might have the dlls in the GAC, and others dont.

Comment: yes, they are included in the same folder as the EXE. if it isn't in the same folder, an error is thrown, I've tested this scenario, so had included them to be copied to the build folder. so this is working too ...

Comment: You can try adding a tracer in there, like a basic string var per line, and then throw that along with the error. See where exactly it's erroring.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? The error is only thrown when it hits  _clientcontext.ExecuteQuery(); so I'm not able to figure out which element, if any, is causing this? Could you pls give me an example or link which could point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: d'oh, good point. my bad. Try removing the XML call for now, and see if you can just get the web title, or the list name. Might help to ensure it really is the XML piece and not another piece.

Comment: i will try and post back. if you have a minute, could you pls have a look at - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67478/date-from-list-being-displayed-wrong-on-graph-created-programmatically I am stuck on another issue with the same program. thanks a lot for your help :)